# How to get the time at which web service is called

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to get the date/time at which a web service is called.
I also want the parameter list which is passed to the web service.

Comment: Where do you want this information? At the client, or the server? Surely you already have the parameters at both sides, and you can just use DateTime.UtcNow to find the current time...

Comment: need some more info, such as code sample or what you did

Comment: Perhaps the term "log" (or "logging") should be in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use System.DateTime.Now()  in the calling function to get the Date and Time